# How to add MS bot to slack?

Tags: bots, slack

I have aqueation that I follow those steps which are provided by https://dev.botframework.com/ to attach my bot to slack ,but I didn't get  'Add Credentials' tab .Do you know what happened and how to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click add button in channel panel

Answer (score 0):

It moved to the Basic Information tab.